# How to replicate threejs.org/editor behavior for envMap in code with MTLLoader?

Tags: three.js

When creating a material in the editor at [threejs.org/editor](http://threejs.org/editor), there is a simple `envMap` field that allows you to upload a single image to be used as the environment map. I need to replicate this behavior in code using the MTLLoader. Here is my code:

```
var mtl_loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

mtl_loader.setBaseUrl(model_base_url);
mtl_loader.setPath(model_base_url);
mtl_loader.load(model_mtl_name, function(materials) {
  materials.preload();

  var obj_loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  obj_loader.setMaterials(materials);
  obj_loader.setPath(model_base_url);
  obj_loader.load(model_obj_name, function(object) {

    scene.add( object );
    render();

  }, onProgress, onError);
});
```

But where do I include that environment map image? Obviously the editor is turning it into some THREE object.

Comment: Some materials have an `envMap` property which accepts a texture

Comment: @2pha Any guidance as to how I can create a texture from a single image and set the material's `envMap` property to that texture?  Specifically when the material is being created by the MTLLoader?

Comment: To just load a texture use the [TextureLoader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader) class. I'm not sure about the MTLLoader class as I don't use it, but take a look at the source of [this demo](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html). I'm not sure how the MTLLoader class handles environment maps. take a look at the [source of the MTLLoader class](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js)